# AngularJS directive to limit a container to a certain number of lines

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive to limit a container (div, p, etc.) to a certain number of lines. I took the code from [Detect browser wrapped lines via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887372/detect-browser-wrapped-lines-via-javascript/12887995#12887995) and wrapped it in a directive and added some checking for number of lines.

The issue I am having is that I am dependent on jQuery because I don't know exactly how to inject text into a div, and then do calculations to create lines, because angular has a digest cycle I don't know how to get around.

Here is my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/DTUjRxEjrXZiA25Kal4u?p=preview

```
app.directive('lineLimit', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'temp.html',
    scope: {
        text: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log("limit", attrs.lineLimit);
      var $cont = $(elem).children('.title-container'); 
      $cont.text(scope.text);  
      var text_arr = $cont.text().split(' ');
      for (i = 0; i < text_arr.length; i++) {
          text_arr[i] = '<span>' + text_arr[i] + ' </span>';
      }

      $cont.html(text_arr.join(''));
      var $wordSpans = $cont.find('span');

      var lineArray = [],
          lineIndex = 0,
          lineStart = true,
          lineEnd = false

          $wordSpans.each(function(idx) {
              var pos = $(this).position();
              var top = pos.top;

              if (lineStart) {
                  lineArray[lineIndex] = [idx];
                  lineStart = false;
              } else {
                  var $next = $(this).next();
                  if ($next.length) {
                      if ($next.position().top > top) {
                          lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
                          lineIndex++;
                          lineStart = true
                      }
                  } else {
                      lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
                  }
              }

          });
      for (var i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
          var start = lineArray[i][0],
              end = lineArray[i][1] + 1;

          /* no end value pushed to array if only one word last line*/
          if (!end) {
              $wordSpans.eq(start).wrap('<span class="line_wrap">')
          } else {
              $wordSpans.slice(start, end).wrapAll('<span class="line_wrap">');
          }

      }
      //console.log('children', $cont.children().length)
      $.each($cont.children(), function(index, value){
        //console.log(index+1)
        if(index+1 > attrs.lineLimit){
          value.remove();
        }
      });
      var sub = $cont.text().substring(0, $cont.text().length-3)
      $cont.text(sub+'...');
    }
  };
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to limit a container to a certain number of lines and show an ellipsis on the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good answer can be found here:
https://github.com/dibari/angular-ellipsis

```
/**
 *  Angular directive to truncate multi-line text to visible height
 *
 *  @param bind (angular bound value to append) REQUIRED
 *  @param ellipsisAppend (string) string to append at end of truncated text after ellipsis, can be HTML OPTIONAL
 *  @param ellipsisSymbol (string) string to use as ellipsis, replaces default '...' OPTIONAL
 *  @param ellipsisAppendClick (function) function to call if ellipsisAppend is clicked (ellipsisAppend must be clicked) OPTIONAL
 *
 *  @example <p data-ellipsis data-ng-bind="boundData"></p>
 *  @example <p data-ellipsis data-ng-bind="boundData" data-ellipsis-symbol="---"></p>
 *  @example <p data-ellipsis data-ng-bind="boundData" data-ellipsis-append="read more"></p>
 *  @example <p data-ellipsis data-ng-bind="boundData" data-ellipsis-append="read more" data-ellipsis-append-click="displayFull()"></p>
 *
 */

(function(ng, app){

    "use strict";

    app.directive('ellipsis', function($timeout, $window) {

        return {
            restrict    : 'A',
            scope       : {
                ngBind              : '=',
                ellipsisAppend      : '@',
                ellipsisAppendClick : '&',
                ellipsisSymbol      : '@'
            },
            compile : function(elem, attr, linker) {

                return function(scope, element, attributes) {
                    /* Window Resize Variables */
                        attributes.lastWindowResizeTime = 0;
                        attributes.lastWindowResizeWidth = 0;
                        attributes.lastWindowResizeHeight = 0;
                        attributes.lastWindowTimeoutEvent = null;
                    /* State Variables */
                        attributes.isTruncated = false;

                    function buildEllipsis() {
                        if (typeof(scope.ngBind) !== 'undefined') {
                            var bindArray = scope.ngBind.split(" "),
                                i = 0,
                                ellipsisSymbol = (typeof(attributes.ellipsisSymbol) !== 'undefined') ? attributes.ellipsisSymbol : '&hellip;',
                                appendString = (typeof(scope.ellipsisAppend) !== 'undefined' && scope.ellipsisAppend !== '') ? ellipsisSymbol + '<span>' + scope.ellipsisAppend + '</span>' : ellipsisSymbol;

                            attributes.isTruncated = false;
                            element.html(scope.ngBind);

                            // If text has overflow
                            if (isOverflowed(element)) {
                                var bindArrayStartingLength = bindArray.length,
                                    initialMaxHeight = element[0].clientHeight;

                                element.html(scope.ngBind + appendString);

                                // Set complete text and remove one word at a time, until there is no overflow
                                for ( ; i < bindArrayStartingLength; i++) {
                                    bindArray.pop();
                                    element.html(bindArray.join(" ") + appendString);

                                    if (element[0].scrollHeight < initialMaxHeight || isOverflowed(element) === false) {
                                        attributes.isTruncated = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                // If append string was passed and append click function included
                                if (ellipsisSymbol != appendString && typeof(scope.ellipsisAppendClick) !== 'undefined' && scope.ellipsisAppendClick !== '' ) {
                                    element.find('span').bind("click", function (e) {
                                        scope.$apply(scope.ellipsisAppendClick);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                   /**
                    *   Test if element has overflow of text beyond height or max-height
                    *
                    *   @param element (DOM object)
                    *
                    *   @return bool
                    *
                    */
                    function isOverflowed(thisElement) {
                        return thisElement[0].scrollHeight > thisElement[0].clientHeight;
                    }

                   /**
                    *   Watchers
                    */

                       /**
                        *   Execute ellipsis truncate on ngBind update
                        */
                        scope.$watch('ngBind', function () {
                            buildEllipsis();
                        });

                       /**
                        *   Execute ellipsis truncate on ngBind update
                        */
                        scope.$watch('ellipsisAppend', function () {
                            buildEllipsis();
                        });

                       /**
                        *   When window width or height changes - re-init truncation
                        */
                        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
                            $timeout.cancel(attributes.lastWindowTimeoutEvent);

                            attributes.lastWindowTimeoutEvent = $timeout(function() {
                                if (attributes.lastWindowResizeWidth != window.innerWidth || attributes.lastWindowResizeHeight != window.innerHeight) {
                                    buildEllipsis();
                                }

                                attributes.lastWindowResizeWidth = window.innerWidth;
                                attributes.lastWindowResizeHeight = window.innerHeight;
                            }, 75);
                        });


                };
            }
        };
    });

})(angular, exampleApp);
```

Comment: This is an javascript solution, not a CSS solution

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to just use css for this, implementing an ellipsis can be done as such:

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
}
strong {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    max-height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text-title:after {
    content: '...';
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 26px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
.box {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    max-height: 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 14px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    position: relative;
}
.box:after {
    content: '...';
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    bottom: 0;
}
.text-body {
    position: relative;
}
.text-body:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 14px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
}
.text-inner {
    width: 90px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

First count the number of characters on a line. Than add up all of the lines. Finally, if in your loop if that # of lines is above a certain #, than inject the css via a directive to add the ellipsis.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: This is really not a great example, the ellipsis is always at the end of the box