# Select and span wrap first and last word within each line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Would it be possible to wrap the first and last word within each line of text in a heading with jQuery?

I have looked into `lettering.js` and others, yet have been unable to create the perfect result.

**Desired result:**

```
<h1>This is text within a <span>line</span>
 That is wrapped within a span <span>based</span>
 on calculated jQuery <span>somehow.</span></h1>
```

Any help here would be wonderful!

Comment: What did *you* try?

Comment: Do you mean new lines in browser, when `<h1>` text doesn't fit in screen (or parent) width?

Comment: Yes, it means lines in browser.

Comment: @george I have tried jQuery with nth-of-type selectors but am not able to target per line break.  This very well may be an impossible request. But javascript is not necessarily my specialty, I was hoping to learn something new for the solve.

Comment: So this should be fully responsive and recalculate if you are resizing the browser manually or viewing on a mobile device?

Comment: @Brock Apologies, I wasn't clear. Please post the code you are currently trying.

Comment: There is only one line here, it is not broken up by any HTML line breaks. Is there something applied to the span to break the line?

Comment: This might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887372/detect-browser-wrapped-lines-via-javascript

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be responsive. But would be nice.

Comment: @Brock See MonkeyZeus's link. I'd have thought wrapping all words in `<span>`s and then testing the position of each would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @monkeyZeus That is massively helpful! Thank you. It often is just knowing the correct questions to ask.

Comment: No problem, good luck on your quest to learn something new!...and apparently challenging =)

Comment: @Brock Is that what you wanted? May we close it as duplicated?

Comment: Yes, I think that answered my questions.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $textVal = $("h1").html();
    var lines = $textVal.split((/\n/g)||[]);
    var newText = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        var tmp = lines[i].split(" ");
        for(var j = 0; j < tmp.length; j++){
            if(j + 1 === tmp.length) tmp[j] = "<span>"+tmp[j]+"</span>";
            newText.push(tmp[j]+" ");
        }
    }
    $("h1").html(newText);
});
```

```css
span{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is some
    text that i
    am testing with
    allright!?</h1>
```