# How to detect a line break in a <p> tag and print something after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `p` with some `span` inside that specify what part of text must be underlined with an animated `div` when I see it, detecting with the `scrollTop()`.

Is there no problem when all the text its in the same line but when the text in `span` have a line break I don't know how to create the `div`.

This s my code, I quit the animation to simplify.

```js
  var subrayados_offset = [];
  var subrayados_element = [];
  var subrayados_bg = [];
  var subrayados_delay = 0;


 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.subrayado').each(function(index, element) {
   subrayados_offset[index] = $(this).offset().top;
   subrayados_element[index] = $(this);
   $(this).append("<div class='subrayado_bg' style='width:100%; height:100%; background-color:red; position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-1;'></div>");
   subrayados_bg[index] = $(this).find(".subrayado_bg");
  });
 });

   setInterval(function() {
       for (var i = subrayados_offset.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var sub_obj = subrayados_bg[i];
       //console.log(subrayados_bg[i]+" "+jQuery(window).scrollTop()+" "+puntoDesplegar);

        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= subrayados_offset[i]-400 && jQuery(window).scrollTop() < subrayados_offset[i]) {
         //TweenMax.killTweensOf(sub_obj);
      //TweenMax.to(sub_obj, 0.5, {delay:subrayados_delay, width:"100%", ease:Power4.easeInOut});
        }
        else{
         //TweenMax.killTweensOf(sub_obj);
         //TweenMax.to(sub_obj, 0.5, {delay:subrayados_delay, width:"0%", ease:Power4.easeInOut});
        }
        subrayados_delay += 0.1;
       }
       subrayados_delay = 0;
        
   }, 500);
```

```css
p{width: 300px;}
.subrayado{ position: relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span class="subrayado">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultricies ultrices enim in condimentum. Nullam sollicitudin varius enim sit amet rutrum. Nam consequat vitae dolor eu pharetra. <span class="subrayado">Morbi vestibulum felis tristique velit</span> varius maximus. Sed venenatis, velit fringilla viverra dictum, magna quam faucibus est, sed congue augue enim a sem. Cras ut tristique enim. Quisque aliquam risus vitae erat lacinia venenatis. </p>


HOW IT MUST BEE

<p><span class="subrayado">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultricies ultrices enim in condimentum. Nullam sollicitudin varius enim sit amet rutrum. Nam consequat vitae dolor eu pharetra. <span class="subrayado">Morbi vestibulum </span><span class="subrayado">felis tristique velit</span> varius maximus. Sed venenatis, velit fringilla viverra dictum, magna quam faucibus est, sed congue augue enim a sem. Cras ut tristique enim. Quisque aliquam risus vitae erat lacinia venenatis. </p>
```

I try to select the linebreak using RegExp but I don't know the correct query.

Comment: I don't think you can detect where the browser auto-breaks long text via RegExp. It's sort of a hack, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12887995/5285945) to a similar problem uses a workaround that involves wrapping ever word in a span and checking how far said span is from the top. Here's [another workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3744583/5285945) that splits the paragraph text by spaces and watches for vertical increases as it puts the text back together.

Comment: Thanks @Max Starkenburg, I can use  the [second workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps/3744583#3744583) to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a `span` after the linebreak using the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps/3744583#3744583) provided by @Max Starkenburg this is the code that I write:

```
if(current.text(current.text() + ' ' + words[i]).height() > height){
    current.text(current.text().split(words[i])[0] + '</span> <span class="subrayar">' + words[i]);
    height = current.height();
}
```

With this, after add the new word, I detect the height and, if it is bigger (is in the next line), I split this word and add it again but writting the `span` tags.

In the snippet below you can see all the code.

I add a class to show the `span` when is in the next line.

```js
var subrayados_offset = [];
  var subrayados_element = [];
  var subrayados_bg = [];


 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.subrayado').each(function(index, element) {
   var current = $(this);
      var text = current.text();
      
      var words = text.split(' ');
      
      current.text(words[0]);
      var height = current.height();
      
      for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
       //console.log(height+" "+words[i]+" "+current.height()+" "+words[i+1]);
          if (i == 0) {
        current.text(words[0]);
       }
       else{
        if(current.text(current.text() + ' ' + words[i]).height() > height){
         console.log(current.text().split(words[i])[0]);
               current.text(current.text().split(words[i])[0] + '</span> <span class="subrayar other_span">' + words[i]);
               height = current.height();
         
           }            
       }  
      }
      
      $(this).html('<span class="subrayar">'+current.text()+'</span>');

   //$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(\w+|\S+)/g, '</span>$1<span class="subrayado">'));
  });

  $('.subrayar').each(function(index, element) {
   subrayados_offset[index] = $(this).offset().top;
   subrayados_element[index] = $(this);
   $(this).append("<div class='subrayado_bg' style='width:100%; height:100%; background-color:red; position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-1;'></div>");
   subrayados_bg[index] = $(this).find(".subrayado_bg");
  });
 });
```

```css
p{width: 300px;}
.subrayar{ position: relative; }
.other_span{ background-color: blue !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span class="subrayado">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultricies ultrices enim in condimentum. Nullam sollicitudin varius enim sit amet rutrum. Nam consequat vitae dolor eu pharetra. <span class="subrayado">Morbi vestibulum felis tristique velit varius maximus.</span> Sed venenatis, velit fringilla viverra dictum, magna quam faucibus est, sed congue augue enim a sem. Cras ut tristique enim. Quisque aliquam risus vitae erat lacinia venenatis. </p>
```