# How can I get the last line of HTML text with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

For example:

```
<p>asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass</p>
```

[How can I get the last line of HTML text with Javascript?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6pwb.png)

Comment: This is not a trivial task, since auto-wrapped lines don't actually exist. Please show your attempt. Or, a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12887995/1169519 ?

Comment: The only (I think) way that would be possible is with a XHR request.

Comment: @D.Pardal How would an AJAX call solve this problem?

Comment: We request the current document from the server, split the text response by line breaks and then we use the last one in the array. Maybe that's not exactly what the asker wanted.

Comment: More important is, what you want to do with last line text? May be there are some possibilities depending on use case.

Comment: I want to do it

When the last character of the last line is a period, the whole content font is reduced.

Comment: The width is uncertain

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
/[^\r\n]+$/g
```

```js
const regex = /[^\r\n]+$/g;
const str = `asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass
asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas 
ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass asdfas ass
asdfas ass`;
let m;

var result = str.match(regex);
console.log(result[0]);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question. They are trying to detect auto-wrapped lines from HTML, which don't contain any new-line characters.

Comment: I didn't find this clear from the question description.

Comment: I want to do it When the last character of the last line is a period, the whole content font is reduced.The width is uncertain