# JS detect when an html element wraps down

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to scroll down to an element when it is created in a div, or when the element wraps down so you can always see the entire text since the text is added slowly to the element.

I have already got a way to auto-scroll to elements when they are created using element.scrollIntoView().

```js
this.setText = function (text) {
        this.text = text
        this.progress = move
        this.element.innerHTML = '[Player]>'
        this.element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
    }

    this.run = function () {
        if (this.progress < this.text.length) {
            // Add animation for different speeds of typing keys
            this.progress += 0.8 * Math.random()
        } else {
            this.progress = this.text.length
        }
        // Draw the text at the current line number
        const currLine = Math.floor(clamp(this.progress, 0, this.text.length))
        this.element.innerHTML = '[Player]>' + this.text.slice(0, currLine)
    }
```

That is the way I add text to the element slowly. I would like to detect the wrap instead of repeatedly scrolling into view the element

Edit: I would have liked to detect when the element wraps not see if it has wrapped i.e. something like window.onElementWrap() but I can work with what you have given me.

The way I can solve my issue is each loop checking if the height is different from the stored height, and if it is, scrolling it into view as well as setting the stored height to the current height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect browser wrapped lines via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887372/detect-browser-wrapped-lines-via-javascript)

Comment: @weegee The last sentence of the question: "I would like to **detect the wrap** instead of repeatedly scrolling into view the element".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the element's [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) (eg: `this.element.offsetHeight`), it will change when the text wraps to a new line.

Here is an example:

```js
const text = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis. Lectus quam id leo in. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo. Massa eget egestas purus viverra. Gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. In massa tempor nec feugiat. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a. Ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan. Lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus. Justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id. Et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum. Pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit.`

let lines = text.match(/.{150}/g);
lines = [...lines, ...lines];
lines = [...lines, ...lines];

let index = 0;
let prevHeight = testElement.offsetHeight;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  testElement.textContent += lines[index];

  const currentHeight = testElement.offsetHeight;
  if (currentHeight > prevHeight) {
    window.scroll(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + (currentHeight - prevHeight));
  }

  prevHeight = currentHeight;

  index++;
  if (index >= lines.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 100);
```

```html
<div id="testElement"></div>
```