# JS code only wraps lines in a span on the first set of text, doesn't do it for the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, split

I have a JS code that I got from "[Detect browser wrapped lines via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887372/detect-browser-wrapped-lines-via-javascript)" that wraps each line into a `<span>`. It works when there's one set of text to wrap inside a `<div>` but doesn't work if there's another set to wrap.

You can see in my example code below, the first set of text will work (green line above the text) but the second set will not.

```js
$(".emails .multi-items").each(function (i) {
  var $cont = $('#content')

  var text_arr = $cont.text().split(' ');
  
  for (i = 0; i < text_arr.length; i++) {
      text_arr[i] = '<span>' + text_arr[i] + ' </span>';
  }
  
  $cont.html(text_arr.join(''));
  
  $wordSpans = $cont.find('span');
  
  var lineArray = [],
      lineIndex = 0,
      lineStart = true,
      lineEnd = false
  
      $wordSpans.each(function(idx) {
          var pos = $(this).position();
          var top = pos.top;
  
          if (lineStart) {
              lineArray[lineIndex] = [idx];
              lineStart = false;
  
          } else {
              var $next = $(this).next();
  
              if ($next.length) {
                  if ($next.position().top > top) {
                      lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
                      lineIndex++;
                      lineStart = true
                  }
              } else {
                  lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
              }
          }
  
      });
  
  
  //console.log( lineArray)
  for (i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
      var start = lineArray[i][0],
          end = lineArray[i][1] + 1;
  
      /* no end value pushed to array if only one word last line*/
      if (!end) {
          $wordSpans.eq(start).wrap('<span class="line_wrap">')
      } else {
          $wordSpans.slice(start, end).wrapAll('<span class="line_wrap">');
      }
  
  };
});
```

```css
.line_wrap{ border-top: 1px solid green}
.message-contain {padding:35px 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emails">
<ul class="multi-items">
  <div class="message-contain">
      <div id="content">
          Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there. The other day the grass was brown, now it’s green because I ain’t give up. Never surrender. Every chance I get, I water the plants, Lion! In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. You do know, you do know that they don’t want you to have lunch. I’m keeping it real with you, so what you going do is have lunch.
      </div>
  </div>
<div class="message-contain">
  <div id="content">
  Fan luv. You smart, you loyal, you a genius. We don’t see them, we will never see them. In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. A major key, never panic. Don’t panic, when it gets crazy and rough, don’t panic, stay calm. The key to more success is to have a lot of pillows. You see the hedges, how I got it shaped up? It’s important to shape up your hedges, it’s like getting a haircut, stay fresh. Let me be clear, you have to make it through the jungle to make it to paradise, that’s the key, Lion!
  </div>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, `$('#content')` will only find the first DIV with that ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid - there should only be one element with a particular ID in a document, so the `$('#content')` is only finding the first `#content`.

Use classes instead, and select the `.content`s with

```
$(".emails .multi-items .content").each(function() {
  var $cont = $(this);
  // ...
```

```js
$(".emails .multi-items .content").each(function() {
  var $cont = $(this);

  var text_arr = $cont.text().split(' ');

  for (i = 0; i < text_arr.length; i++) {
    text_arr[i] = '<span>' + text_arr[i] + ' </span>';
  }

  $cont.html(text_arr.join(''));

  $wordSpans = $cont.find('span');

  var lineArray = [],
    lineIndex = 0,
    lineStart = true,
    lineEnd = false

  $wordSpans.each(function(idx) {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    var top = pos.top;

    if (lineStart) {
      lineArray[lineIndex] = [idx];
      lineStart = false;

    } else {
      var $next = $(this).next();

      if ($next.length) {
        if ($next.position().top > top) {
          lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
          lineIndex++;
          lineStart = true
        }
      } else {
        lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
      }
    }

  });


  //console.log( lineArray)
  for (i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
    var start = lineArray[i][0],
      end = lineArray[i][1] + 1;

    /* no end value pushed to array if only one word last line*/
    if (!end) {
      $wordSpans.eq(start).wrap('<span class="line_wrap">')
    } else {
      $wordSpans.slice(start, end).wrapAll('<span class="line_wrap">');
    }

  };
});
```

```css
.line_wrap {
  border-top: 1px solid green
}

.message-contain {
  padding: 35px 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emails">
  <ul class="multi-items">
    <div class="message-contain">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there. The other day the grass was brown, now it’s
        green because I ain’t give up. Never surrender. Every chance I get, I water the plants, Lion! In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. You do know, you do know
        that they don’t want you to have lunch. I’m keeping it real with you, so what you going do is have lunch.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-contain">
      <div class="content">
        Fan luv. You smart, you loyal, you a genius. We don’t see them, we will never see them. In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. A major key, never panic. Don’t panic,
        when it gets crazy and rough, don’t panic, stay calm. The key to more success is to have a lot of pillows. You see the hedges, how I got it shaped up? It’s important to shape up your hedges, it’s like getting a haircut, stay fresh. Let me be clear,
        you have to make it through the jungle to make it to paradise, that’s the key, Lion!
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You used the id `content` twice. Change it to a class and it works.

```js
$(".emails .multi-items").each(function (i) {
  var $cont = $('.content')

  var text_arr = $cont.text().split(' ');
  
  for (i = 0; i < text_arr.length; i++) {
      text_arr[i] = '<span>' + text_arr[i] + ' </span>';
  }
  
  $cont.html(text_arr.join(''));
  
  $wordSpans = $cont.find('span');
  
  var lineArray = [],
      lineIndex = 0,
      lineStart = true,
      lineEnd = false
  
      $wordSpans.each(function(idx) {
          var pos = $(this).position();
          var top = pos.top;
  
          if (lineStart) {
              lineArray[lineIndex] = [idx];
              lineStart = false;
  
          } else {
              var $next = $(this).next();
  
              if ($next.length) {
                  if ($next.position().top > top) {
                      lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
                      lineIndex++;
                      lineStart = true
                  }
              } else {
                  lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
              }
          }
  
      });
  
  
  //console.log( lineArray)
  for (i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
      var start = lineArray[i][0],
          end = lineArray[i][1] + 1;
  
      /* no end value pushed to array if only one word last line*/
      if (!end) {
          $wordSpans.eq(start).wrap('<span class="line_wrap">')
      } else {
          $wordSpans.slice(start, end).wrapAll('<span class="line_wrap">');
      }
  
  };
});
```

```css
.line_wrap{ border-top: 1px solid green}
.message-contain {padding:35px 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emails">
<ul class="multi-items">
  <div class="message-contain">
      <div class="content">
          Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there. The other day the grass was brown, now it’s green because I ain’t give up. Never surrender. Every chance I get, I water the plants, Lion! In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. You do know, you do know that they don’t want you to have lunch. I’m keeping it real with you, so what you going do is have lunch.
      </div>
  </div>
<div class="message-contain">
  <div class="content">
  Fan luv. You smart, you loyal, you a genius. We don’t see them, we will never see them. In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. A major key, never panic. Don’t panic, when it gets crazy and rough, don’t panic, stay calm. The key to more success is to have a lot of pillows. You see the hedges, how I got it shaped up? It’s important to shape up your hedges, it’s like getting a haircut, stay fresh. Let me be clear, you have to make it through the jungle to make it to paradise, that’s the key, Lion!
  </div>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```