# How to split and wrap lines in a span in each section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I using "[Detect browser wrapped lines via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887372/detect-browser-wrapped-lines-via-javascript)" as a way to wrap each line in a `<span>`. However, I'm having a problem if there's more than one element to split and wrap.

For example: If I have more than one section to split and wraps like:

```
<div class="emails">
<ul class="multi-items">
  <div class="message-contain">
   <div id="content">
       1 - Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there. 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="message-contain">
  <div id="content">
       2 - The key to more success is to get a massage once a week, very important, major key, cloth talk. Eliptical talk. 
  </div>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

It will take all the text in `.content`, split and wrap them in an a `<span>` and duplicate them. So the put looks like this;

```
<div class="emails">
<ul class="multi-items">
  <div class="message-contain">
   <div id="content">
       <span class="line_wrap">1 - Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success.</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">They will try to close the door on you, just open it.</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there.</span> 
       <span class="line_wrap">2 - The key to more success is to get a massage once</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">a week, very important, major key, cloth talk.</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">Eliptical talk.</span> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="message-contain">
  <div id="content">
       <span class="line_wrap">1 - Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success.</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">They will try to close the door on you, just open it.</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there.</span> 
       <span class="line_wrap">2 - The key to more success is to get a massage once</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">a week, very important, major key, cloth talk.</span>
       <span class="line_wrap">Eliptical talk.</span>
  </div>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

I added 1 - and 2 - to show that they duplicate. There suppose to be in different sections, not to be in all of them.

Anyway on how to split and wrap each line in a `<span>` in each section and not create duplicate content?

Working example: https://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/poJwaXv

JS Code:

```
$(".emails .multi-items").each(function (i) {
var $cont = $('.emails .multi-items .message-contain #content')
var text_arr = $cont.text().split(' ');
for (i = 0; i < text_arr.length; i++) {
  text_arr[i] = '<span>' + text_arr[i] + ' </span>';
}

$cont.html(text_arr.join(''));
$wordSpans = $cont.find('span');

var lineArray = [],
  lineIndex = 0,
  lineStart = true,
  lineEnd = false

  $wordSpans.each(function(idx) {
      var pos = $(this).position();
      var top = pos.top;

      if (lineStart) {
          lineArray[lineIndex] = [idx];
          lineStart = false;

      } else {
          var $next = $(this).next();

          if ($next.length) {
              if ($next.position().top > top) {
                  lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
                  lineIndex++;
                  lineStart = true
              }
          } else {
              lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
          }
      }

  });


 //console.log( lineArray)
 for (i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
  var start = lineArray[i][0],
      end = lineArray[i][1] + 1;

  /* no end value pushed to array if only one word last line*/
  if (!end) {
      $wordSpans.eq(start).wrap('<span class="line_wrap">')
  } else {
      $wordSpans.slice(start, end).wrapAll('<span class="line_wrap">');
  }

 };
});
```

Comment: so you want wrap each line in span right without duplicating content ?

Comment: Yes. Currently it splits and wraps and then outputs duplicating content in both elements as shown above in the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a vanilla JavaScript version of this:

```
function wrapNewLines(targetSelector, wrapEl = 'span', wrapClass = 'new-line') {
  const content = document.querySelectorAll(targetSelector)
  content.forEach(section => {
    let sectionWidth = section.getBoundingClientRect().width
    let words = section.innerText.split(/( )/g)
    section.innerHTML = words.map(word =>`<span>${word}</span>`).join('')
    let lines = []
    let line = []
    let lineWidth = 0
    let spans = section.querySelectorAll('span')
    spans.forEach((span, i) => {
      let spanWidth = span.getBoundingClientRect().width
      if (lineWidth + spanWidth <= sectionWidth - 4) {
        line.push(span)
        lineWidth += spanWidth
      } else {
        lines.push(line)
        line = []
        lineWidth = 0
        line.push(span)
        lineWidth += spanWidth
      }
    })
    if (line.length) lines.push(line)
    let newLines = lines
      .map(
        line =>
          `<${wrapEl} class=${wrapClass}>${line
            .map(span => span.innerText)
            .join('')}</${wrapEl}>`
      )
      .join('')
    section.innerHTML = newLines
  })
}

wrapNewLines ('.emails .multi-items .message-contain #content');
```

[Here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/brendan-c/2c3d534e75176fdfa10609a9efeca99a)

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Where do you put it? The example provided didn't help. `function wrapNewLines('#content') {` didn't work.

Comment: All you need to do is copy the function above, and call it underneath like so: https://codepen.io/brendan-c/pen/ZEGZbPm

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Now it works. Edit your answer to include `wrapNewLines ('.emails .multi-items .message-contain #content');` and it can reset the vote count.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$(".emails .multi-items").each(function(i) {
          var $cont = $(".message-contain #content");

          var text_arr = $cont.text().split(". ");

          for (i = 0; i < text_arr.length; i++) {
            text_arr[i] = "<span class='line_wrap'>" + text_arr[i] + ". </span>";
          }

          $cont.html(text_arr.join(""));
        });
```

Comment: It still duplicates. https://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/XWbQbwZ That's why I added 1 - and 2 - to show that they duplicate.